# Why is prooftrees putting everything on the same line?

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest, logic, proof-package, prooftrees

I'm trying to do a prooftrees tree like this:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{prooftrees}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
{
    to prove={ A \lor B \lor C \lor D \lor E }
}
    [ A ]
    [ B ]
    [ C ]
\end{prooftree}                                                                                                                     
\end{document}
```

But it currently outputs this:

[image: Current output]

It's all on the same line while I'm trying to get a tree with branches on multiple lines.
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Tried a forest tree, it doesn't work either. Lines are drawn but the letters are all still crammed like in the picture.

Comment: welcome to the site, please could you make your example a complete document that makes the image, so people can reproduce, and test answers.

Comment: `[ A [ B [ C ] ] ]` seems more reasonable input

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Done, still doesn't work though :(

Comment: @egreg That also doesn't work, it looks the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a tree, so it needs *one* root and branches.

For instance

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{prooftrees}

\begin{document}

\begin{prooftree}
{
    to prove={A \lor B \lor C \lor D \lor E}
}
[A
  [ B ]
  [ C
    [ D ]
  ]
]
\end{prooftree}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that, in order to see the real result, you have to look at a PDF output, either running `pdflatex` or `latex+dvips+ps2pdf`; the DVI file will not show the correct output, because TikZ/PGF, which `prooftrees` is based on, uses “specials” that DVI viewers are not able to show.

Comment: I copied your example but it still doesn't work, this is the new [output.](https://i.imgur.com/L7rWeSi.png)  Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @wofinoli Ensure to have the most recent version of `prooftrees`, namely version 0.6 released 2017/02/09.

Comment: This is what's in my log file:  prooftrees.sty    2017/02/09 v0.6 (SVN Rev: 5848)

Comment: Also this is what it says for forest: forest.sty    2017/07/14 v2.1.5 Drawing (linguistic) trees

Comment: @wofinoli That's the same. Did you compile the exact example?

Comment: Yes, I copied and pasted it, and when that didn't work copied it by hand. Neither worked.

Comment: @wofinoli There must be something else on your system. Can you make the log file available for inspection?

Comment: Here is the log file: https://pastebin.com/f0RSMVM5

Comment: @wofinoli You have to look at a PDF; DVI viewers are not able to show TikZ/PGF graphics correctly. Is there any reason for using `latex` and DVI, as opposed to `pdflatex` and PDF?

Comment: Wow that was it. Sorry to be a bother I'm new to this stuff. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The solution is right (+1) but the diagnosis is not technically correct as the OP's tree does have a root. (It wouldn't have a root in a `forest` environment, but it does in a `prooftree` one.)

Comment: The OP's output isn't what you'd expect for a rootless tree anyway. It is actually quite important that the tree in the question isn't rootless, because it has implications for customising a `prooftree` as opposed to a `forest`.

Comment: Can you please change this so that the answer with the tick isn't wrong? The tree isn't rootless when typeset and works perfectly well (even if it is logically incorrect).

Comment: @cfr I wrote “one root and branches”.

Comment: @egreg Yes, but the tree in the question has one root and branches. It would be hard to avoid that given how `prooftrees` works. Unless you go to a lot of trouble, you'll always have one root and branches.

Comment: That is, the problem is not the code at all (though the result may not be the output the user wants). The problem is the backend not supporting Ti*k*Z. The code itself is fine, even if it is illogical.

Comment: @egreg Please this diagnosis is still wrong and it is really misleading. It matters a lot that `prooftree` doesn't work like `forest`.

Answer (score 2):

[egreg is correct regarding the solution, but the diagnosis is wrong.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391871/39222) The problem is not that the tree has no root. It has a perfectly good root. Moreover, it does not superimpose nodes if compiled with an appropriate engine (e.g. pdfTeX).

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{prooftrees}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
{
    to prove={ A \lor B \lor C \lor D \lor E }
}
    [ A ]
    [ B ]
    [ C ]
\end{prooftree} 
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: proof with a strange beginning]

Now, admittedly, this probably is not what you meant or want, but it is reasonably sensible output, given the input.

Suppose we instead try

```
\begin{forest}
    [ A ]
    [ B ]
    [ C ]
\end{forest}
```

which produces

[image: Forest]

This is because Forest takes `[ A ]` to be the root and, hence, the entire tree. Everything after the tree specification is passed to Ti*k*Z, but there are no relevant commands here, so `[ B ]` and `[ C ]` are parsed as text. Since we are inside a `tikzpicture` environment, we are using the `null` font and the text is ignored. Hence, we effectively have

```
\begin{forest}
  [ A ]
\end{forest}
```

The reason that the `prooftree` environment behaves differently is because the tree specified by the user is actually a sub-tree of the tree the environment typesets. `prooftree` embeds the user's tree specification in a larger tree which includes the line numbers, justifications and 'to prove' line, as appropriate. Hence, the inner `forest` environment reads

```
  [ A ]
  [ B ]
  [ C ]
```

as part of the tree specification, so these end up being nodes in the `tikzpicture` and get typeset in the normal font, which is switched back by Ti*k*Z for node text.

The user provided root in a `prooftree` is 'never' the root of the typeset tree. I'm not sure it is possible to make a `prooftree` attempt to set a rootless tree and, although I would not wish to rule this possibility out, I can say that it is most unlikely that anybody would do so by accident.